# GitLab: Setting the server hook causes the protection branch to fail

Tags: gitlab, hook

When I set up a pre-receive server hook for GitLab project, it can work normally, but anyone and any role can directly push the code to this project protection branch (similar to master). When this custom hook is cancelled, the protection branch is normal again, and no one can push the code directly.

Does anyone know what's going on?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

REJECT=0 
JAVA_HOME=/data/jdk1.8.0_144 

CHECK_JAR_HOME=/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitaly-ruby/git-hooks/pre-receive.d

TEMPDIR="tmp_for_scan" 

file_repository_path=`pwd`

sub_str=${file_repository_path%.git*}      
repository_name=${sub_str##*/}
 

check_main() {
     
     check 
}

check() {

    get_all_change_file_and_save

    p3c_jar_check
    


    rm -rf $TEMPDIR

    if [[ $REJECT -ne 0 ]]; then
        exit $REJECT
    fi
}

p3c_jar_check() {
    files_to_check=`find $TEMPDIR -name '*.java'` 

    if [[ -n $files_to_check && $files_to_check != "" ]];then   
        echo -e "ali-p3c-pmd check starting......"

        $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp $CHECK_JAR_HOME/p3c-pmd-2.1.1.jar net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD -d $TEMPDIR  -R rulesets/p3c.xml -f text -shortnames
        
        REJECT=$?
        
        echo -e "ali-p3c-pmd check end......"
        
        if [[ $REJECT == 0 ]] ;then
            echo -e "恭喜你代码通过质量检测！"
        else
            echo -e "请及时修改代码并再次尝试!!"
        fi
    else
        echo 'ali-p3c-pmd pass....' 
    fi
}




get_all_change_file_and_save() {
    
    while read oldrev newrev refname; do
        if test "$oldrev" = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ;then
            oldrev="$newrev^"
        fi

        
        operate_log=`git log $oldrev..$newrev --pretty="%h $refname %B"`
        if [[ $operate_log =~ "merge request" ]];then
            echo "***merge request** continue"
            continue
        fi

        
        files=`git diff --name-only $oldrev $newrev | grep -e ".java$"`
        file_repository_path=`pwd`

        
        if test -n "$files"; then                   
            for file in $files; do                          
                mkdir -p "$TEMPDIR/`dirname $file`" > /dev/null
                git show $newrev:$file > $TEMPDIR/$file   
            done;
        fi
        break           
    done
}


 

check_main
exit $REJECT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Double-check exactly how you have set up your hook, by reviewing "[Chained hooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html#chained-hooks)":

> Server hooks are searched for and executed in the following order of priority:
>
> - Built-in GitLab server hooks. These are not user-customizable.
>   `<project>.git/custom_hooks/<hook_name>`: Per-project hooks. This was kept for backwards compatibility.
> - `<project>.git/custom_hooks/<hook_name>.d/*`: Location for per-project hooks.
> - `<custom_hooks_dir>/<hook_name>.d/*`: Location for all executable global hook files except editor backup files.

The goal is to make sure you do not override the default pre-receive hook, which is reserved for branch protection.